# Jackson/JSON: ExceptionInInitializerError upon calling new ObjectMapper()

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, jackson

I'm using Jackson in my Android app. I have a `BroadcastReceiver` for incoming calls that saves information about the entire call, then I save it to a JSON object in a JSON array.

Then, I get the exception below which points to the line where I call `ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper()`. I don't know what to do since I did not write those classes. Help?

```
09-04 09:08:58.220: E/AndroidRuntime(4445): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-04 09:08:58.220: E/AndroidRuntime(4445): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
09-04 09:08:58.220: E/AndroidRuntime(4445):     at com.ourcompany.appname.IncomingCallDetector.saveLog(IncomingCallDetector.java:80)
09-04 09:08:58.220: E/AndroidRuntime(4445):     at com.ourcompany.appname.IncomingCallDetector.onReceive(IncomingCallDetector.java:70)
09-04 09:08:58.220: E/AndroidRuntime(4445):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2816)
09-04 09:08:58.220: E/AndroidRuntime(4445):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$3200(ActivityThread.java:126)
09-04 09:08:58.220: E/AndroidRuntime(4445):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2088)
09-04 09:08:58.220: E/AndroidRuntime(4445):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-04 09:08:58.220: E/AndroidRuntime(4445):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
09-04 09:08:58.220: E/AndroidRuntime(4445):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4633)
09-04 09:08:58.220: E/AndroidRuntime(4445):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-04 09:08:58.220: E/AndroidRuntime(4445):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
09-04 09:08:58.220: E/AndroidRuntime(4445):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
09-04 09:08:58.220: E/AndroidRuntime(4445):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
09-04 09:08:58.220: E/AndroidRuntime(4445):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-04 09:08:58.220: E/AndroidRuntime(4445): Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
09-04 09:08:58.220: E/AndroidRuntime(4445):     at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.<clinit>(ObjectMapper.java:197)
09-04 09:08:58.220: E/AndroidRuntime(4445):     ... 13 more
09-04 09:08:58.220: E/AndroidRuntime(4445): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAutoDetect
09-04 09:08:58.220: E/AndroidRuntime(4445):     at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.VisibilityChecker$Std.<clinit>(VisibilityChecker.java:169)
09-04 09:08:58.220: E/AndroidRuntime(4445):     ... 14 more
```

My broadcast receiver is here: http://pastie.org/4661134

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What seems to happen is that JsonAutoDetect is not added to your project. Make sure it is included in the apk (see classpath part in eclipse if you are using eclipse)

Comment: I actually just have the .jar files for jackson-core and the one for data binding. I'm aware there's another one. Do you mean I should include that too?

Comment: yes. you need jackson annotations. See this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10094300/webapp-noclassdeffound-jsonautodetect

Comment: Awesome, thank you. I just have to wait for 9 more minutes to choose your answer.