# Proguard: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper

Tags: java, javafx, jackson, proguard, obfuscation

We are trying to use Proguard 5.2 to obfuscate an application in  JavaFX that has Jackson Json as it's Json serializer. The application works fine without the use of Proguard, but when we obfuscate our code, we get an exception just by instantiating a new ObjectMapper, Java claims it can not find this class.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
```

Exception message:

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$155(LauncherImpl.java:182)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper
    at br.ufmg.dcc.isajavafx.excelreader.ISAExcelTemplate.toJSON(ISAExcelTemplate.java:315)
    at br.ufmg.dcc.isajavafx.controller.MainController.checkConfigurationFiles(MainController.java:607)
    at br.ufmg.dcc.isajavafx.controller.MainController.initialize(MainController.java:632)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2548)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2425)
    at br.ufmg.dcc.isajavafx.ISAJavaFX.start(ISAJavaFX.java:30)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.lambda$null$49(GtkApplication.java:139)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 15 more
Exception running application mypackage.myclass
```

This is our proguard config file:

```
-libraryjars /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/rt.jar
-libraryjars /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar
-libraryjars target/lib/jackson-annotations-2.7.0.jar
-libraryjars target/lib/jackson-core-2.7.0.jar
-libraryjars target/lib/jackson-databind-2.7.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
-libraryjars target/lib/commonj.sdo-2.1.1.jar
-libraryjars target/lib/commons-codec-1.9.jar
-libraryjars target/lib/controlsfx-8.40.11.jar
-libraryjars target/lib/javax.persistence-2.1.0.jar
-libraryjars target/lib/poi-3.13.jar
-libraryjars target/lib/poi-ooxml-3.13.jar
-libraryjars target/lib/poi-ooxml-schemas-3.13.jar
...
-keepnames class org.codehaus.jackson.** { *; }
-keepnames class com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.**
-keep public class classes.to.be.serialized** {public private protected *;}
```

All the members of the classes.to.be.serialized are public, and some are primitive types, the others that aren't primitives, are also in the package supposed to be ignored.

The problem is that we are getting an error like the Jackson library was not found. The jars are in our classpath before and after the obfuscation.

Answer (score 0):

Solved

The problem was with the jackson-databind version. The other libs version was 2.7.0 and the databind was 2.7.1-SNAPSHOT. I don't why the problem only shows up when the program was obfuscated but the solution was to equalize the jackson libs to the same version.

I also get a hint to solve on this post:
[NoClassDefFoundError JsonAutoDetect while parsing JSON object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10094300/noclassdeffounderror-jsonautodetect-while-parsing-json-object)